# YTPlayerView playing video in table view cell without sound in device

Tags: ios, swift3, uitableview, ytplayerview, ytplayer

I'm playing youtube video using YTPlayerView into table view cell using swift3.0 . When app running in Device then there is no sound of that video but in simulator video playing with sound.

My question is how to play video using YTPlayerView with sound in device? 
Or
Any other library that can play youtube video in table view cell with sound. I'm using Swift3.0

Thank's in advance.

Comment: I've used YTPlayerView in a few of my apps, and haven't had any issues with the sound, including in table view cells. I know this may sound silly, but do you have the phone muted? Alternatively, try hooking it up to another phone.

Comment: Thank you @tww0003

Comment: @tww0003 i have implement YTPlayerView in tableview cell when i scroll down and after reaching at last point when i scroll up YTPlayerView initialise again.how to do it ? i want YTPlayerView load only once in tableview

Comment: @AbecedarioPoint That's because iOS dequeue's and reuses UITableViewCells to manage memory usage. You might could keep it loaded by setting that cell as a strong property on your class and returning the cell at a specific index path, while reusing the other cells, but I'm not 100% sure if that will work.

Comment: @tww0003 thank you for your help i will try